# python django response time long but don't know what's wrong

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, response-time

My django app use django-rest-framework, and MySQL.
I tested my app, but almost functions had long response time. I don't know what is the problem.

This is one of most long response time functions.

```
   180232 function calls (171585 primitive calls) in 1.110 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 757 to 151 due to restriction <0.2>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      105    0.597    0.006    0.597    0.006 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:268(query)
        2    0.154    0.077    0.174    0.087 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:81(__init__)
        4    0.020    0.005    0.020    0.005 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:254(autocommit)
8800/3582    0.010    0.000    0.828    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
    20156    0.010    0.000    0.022    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
  200/100    0.009    0.000    0.886    0.009 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py:479(to_representation)
        2    0.009    0.005    0.009    0.005 {function Connection.set_character_set at 0x109b506a8}
     6920    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
                                      ....
```

This function is first page of list, total count is 1000, page size is 100. Each records join just one table. Query took long time so I changed Django ORM to Raw Query but time is same. (Maybe I used wrong raw query)

Even auth check response time long

```
        2199 function calls (2133 primitive calls) in 0.195 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 419 to 84 due to restriction <0.2>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.153    0.076    0.169    0.084 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:81(__init__)
        4    0.016    0.004    0.016    0.004 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:254(autocommit)
        3    0.014    0.005    0.014    0.005 /Users/jyj/.pyenv/versions/logispot_app_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:268(query)
        2    0.008    0.004    0.008    0.004 {function Connection.set_character_set at 0x109b506a8}
```

I think it must take less than 60ms. (Maybe my thinking is wrong)

Is django query too slow or there are something wrong in my app? I know what is the problem.

- `DEBUG` is `False` in `settings`
- it just local `runserver` not deployed. But response time is almost same when deployed (deployed more fast, but query time same)
- Sorry about poor informations. My web develop experience is just half-year. If you want more, I will try.

**EDIT**
View code

```
class OrderListCreationAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsAdminOrClient,
    )
    pagination_class = StandardListPagination


    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = CacheOrderList.objects.all()
            return queryset
        else:
            return Order.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return CacheOrderListSerializer
        else:
            return OrderSerializer
```

Serializer code

```
class CacheOrderListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    base = CacheBaseSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CacheOrderList
        fields = '__all__'
```

Model code

```
class CacheBase(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order = models.OneToOneField('order.Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cache', primary_key=True)
    driver_user = models.ForeignKey('member.DriverUser', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    load_address = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    load_company = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    load_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    load_time = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unload_address = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    unload_company = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    unload_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    unload_time = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stop_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_round = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_mix = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    car_ton = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=True)
    payment_method = models.BooleanField(default=s.ORDER_PAYMENT_METHOD_ADVANCE)
    contract_fee = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    driver_fee = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    order_fee = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class CacheOrderList(models.Model):
    base = models.OneToOneField(CacheBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_list')
    order_status = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    order_created_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    asignee = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    objects = CacheManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-order_created_time',)
        db_table = 'CacheOrderList'
```

**EDIT2**
[image]
In list function, app already get 100 items, but after that, app query again 1 per 1. Not use already gotten items. So it took 100 * each query spend time.

This is probably because the serializer did not use the records that pagination got. So pagination 2 query + serializer 100 query + others.

I don't know why that happened.

Comment: How many rows you have? Have you tried executing same query in mysql directly?

Comment: about 1000. And I do execute in mysql. It took less than 60ms. I changed code to use raw query(same query) in my app. but time is same with my post results.

Comment: can you post the code as well?

Comment: edit done. just simple list code.

Comment: use django-debug-toolbar to check where the problem is.

Comment: I found problem in list. But don't know why that happened.

Comment: Is there something in your CacheManager that might be causing this?

Comment: Thanks to all opinions. I can solve that for you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in CacheOrderList queryset for base field. This will prepare a queryset cache with Foreign Key associations you provide in the method, which will basically not hit the DB again and again.

**Example**:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        # prepare related models cache using `select_related`
        queryset = CacheOrderList.objects.all().select_related('base')
        return queryset
    else:
        return Order.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw this post. http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/